# force windbg not load symbol

Tags: windbg, symbols

I'm doing crash analysis on some software,and I'm sure there is no pdb file I can get for the sth.exe,but when sth.exe crashs,every time windbg will search a lot of paths and symbol servers.Even when I cut off the vm's network connection,it still pinned for a while to search the sth.exe's pdb.And this leads to a failure in my auto analysis.**Is there a way to tell windbg sth.exe has no pdb,please don't waste time to search it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a file named **symsrv.ini**
in the folder where `windbg is installed`
the directory in this sample is `e:\ewdk\program files\windows kits\10\Debuggers\x86`

create an exclusion section in the file
and add all the unknown pdb's list into it
symsrv wont go searching for them

```
:\>ls -l symsrv.ini
-rw-rw-rw-  1 HP 0 259 2016-08-18 17:43 symsrv.ini

:\>file symsrv.ini
symsrv.ini; ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

:\>cat symsrv.ini
[exclusions]
livekdD.sys
vmm.pdb
livekdD.pdb
vmci.pdb
vsock.pdb
clwvd.pdb
spldr.pdb
vmkbd.pdb
vmnetsrv.pdb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

:\>livekd

LiveKd v5.40 - Execute kd/windbg on a live system
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

!sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts off

kd> .reload /f

SYMSRV:  vmci.pdb is in the file exclusion list
DBGHELP: d:\build\ob\bora-1141980\bora-vmsoft\build\release\crosstalk\windows\wi
n2k\i386\vmci.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for vmci.sys -
DBGHELP: vmci - export symbols

SYMSRV:  vsock.pdb is in the file exclusion list
DBGHELP: d:\build\ob\bora-1253991\bora-vmsoft\build\release\vsock\windows\win2k\
i386\vsock.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for vsock.sys -
DBGHELP: vsock - export symbols

SYMSRV:  vmm.pdb is in the file exclusion list
DBGHELP: m:\src\built\vs2005.sp2\vssp2\usa\ent_volume\i386\sym\sys\vmm.pdb - fil
e not found
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for vmm.sys
DBGHELP: vmm - no symbols loaded

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
vmci                   The system cannot find the file specified : srv*e:\symbols*
                       http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols The SYMSRV client 
                       failed to find a file in the UNC store, or there is an invalid
                       UNC store (an invalid path or thepingme.txt file is not present
                       in the root directory), or the fileis present 
                       in the symbol server exclusion list.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

answer to comment

well for a start there is a setting up exclusion list topic in windbg help

this topic alludes to this file (file is alluded in respect to using the symproxy and is supposed to be created at %windowsdir\system32\inetsrv\"  and doesnt work for symsrv.dll (the registry key also doesnt seem to work )

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556870(v=vs.85).aspx

for me i saw in procmon a failure with NameNotFound error in fastio path   in windbg installation directory
so on a hunch i moved the file from above mentioned path to windbg installation directory
and things seemed to work correctly that was very long back

[image]but subsequently i've seen post from jason shay (MSFT) in osr windbg lists  stating this feature was pushed in windbg 6.4.4 beta

http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=68916

so there isn't any common sense missing just that the corner cases are always difficult to find

Comment: Wow,thanks a lot~And then I find it at windbg help file use keyword  "symsrv.ini".Could I know how do you know this?I've spend a hard time trying to find it in the help file but got nothing.Is there some basic common sense I've missed?

Comment: welli couldnt fit the response in a comment so i edited the post for some tidbits tldr it is a corner case and it is difficult to anticipate and plan for them so there is no common sense missing